# FirebaseInitProvider clase no encontrada

Tags: android, firebase

Al depurar mi proyecto obtengo el siguiente error:

**logcat:**

> 07-03 16:38:51.708 27467-27467/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                          Process: com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp, PID: 27467
>                                                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
>   com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5196)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp-1,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>                                                                                              at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5181)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4788) 
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4728) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:166) 
>                                                                                              at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268) 
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084) 
>                                                                                              at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Este es mi **app.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
            def requested = details.requested
            if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
                if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                    details.useVersion '25.3.0'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        Firma {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('C:/Users/javie/.android/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.Firma
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io'}
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5@aar') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile project(':jtds-1.3.1')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.scottyab:aescrypt:0.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.github.SubhrajyotiSen:library:1.1.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    compile 'com.github.delight-im:Android-SimpleLocation:v1.0.1'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.10'
    compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.alexzh:circleimageview:1.1.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.sdsmdg.tastytoast:tastytoast:0.1.1'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.nguyenhoanglam:ImagePicker:1.1.3'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.4.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.4.2'
    compile 'com.code-troopers.betterpickers:library:3.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.github.SilenceDut:ExpandableLayout:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.github.arimorty:floatingsearchview:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'
    compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.apl-devs:appintro:v4.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
    compile 'com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:3.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

espero puedan ayudarme a solucionar este error, creo que es un error de multidex, pero la verdad no tengo idea

Answer (score 0):

Asegura que el paquete de tu aplicación (application id), sea el correcto dentro de tu build.gradle, actualmente tienes definido :

```
applicationId "com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp"
```

---

No había la gran cantidad de dependencias que tiene definida tu aplicación...Habilita soporte multidex:

```
defaultConfig {
    ....
    ....
    multiDexEnabled = true
}
```

Comment: ese es el paquete de la app, logro hacer correr la app si borro la dependencia compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2', pero deja de funciona mi login con google al borrarla

Comment: Veo que tienes demasiadas dependencias.

Comment: funcionaba todo correcto, hasta que los repositorios se actualizaron desde la version 54 a la 55